# Can I use Top 1 and Order By as part of a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do something like the following.  I need to return a person record that also includes the name of that person's oldest dog (for when a person has >1 dog).  The query below is returning `NULL` for the `dogName`.  (I've checked and there is valid data)  If I remove the `Top 1` and `Order by` parts of the join query it returns a valid `dogName`, but not the 'oldest' dog.  Why does the adding the `TOP 1` and `OrderBy` cause it to return NULL?

```
SELECT
    pt.firstName [FirstName],
    pt.lastName [LastName],
    joinQuery.dogName [dogName]
FROM dbo.PersonTable pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1
            dt.dogName [dogName],
            dt.dogAge  [dogAge]
        FROM
            DogTable dt
        ORDER BY dt.dogAge
    ) joinQuery ON joinQuery.PersonId = pt.Id
WHERE
    pt.firstName = 'john'
```

Note: this is just a similar query to one I'm not allowed to post in a forum.

Also, I'm not an expert by any means so I might be trying to solve this problem incorrectly.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the oldest dog is `ORDER  BY dt.dogage DESC`.

Comment: As per valid data, who owns the oldest dog?

Comment: Did you actually run that query?  The subquery doesn't even have the `PersonId` as a column being returned in it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a join at all:

```
SELECT pt.firstname               [FirstName], 
       pt.lastname                [LastName], 
       (SELECT TOP 1 dt.dogname 
        FROM   dogtable dt 
        WHERE  dt.personid = pt.id 
        ORDER  BY dt.dogage DESC) AS [dogName] 
FROM   dbo.persontable pt 
WHERE  pt.firstname = 'john'
```

Note that the oldest dog is `ORDER  BY dt.dogage DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `ORDER BY` clause needs to have a trailing `DESC` keyword; as you pointed out you wanted to retrieve the 'oldest dog'.

Answer (score 0):

looks ok to me, although i would probably consider Rank() Over() in this situation

although it may be slower in this instance

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid, you are joining by column that is not selected from `DogTable`, also if you want the oldest you can have to `order by desc` or use `max` function.

```
SELECT
    pt.firstName [FirstName],
    pt.lastName [LastName],
    joinQuery.dogName [dogName]
FROM dbo.PersonTable pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1
            dt.PersonId,
            dt.dogName [dogName],
            dt.dogAge  [dogAge]
        FROM
            DogTable dt
        ORDER BY dt.dogAge
    ) joinQuery ON joinQuery.PersonId = pt.Id
WHERE
    pt.firstName = 'john'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query returned NULL is that you were picking 1 dog from the table, not 1 dog per personID, so if 'john' didn't have the youngest (since you didn't order by dogage descending) dog in the table, you weren't going to return a value.  You need a result per PersonID first, then to limit to only the person/people you're interested in.

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` is a good solution for problems like this:

```
SELECT
    pt.firstName [FirstName],
    pt.lastName [LastName],
    pet.dogName [dogName]
FROM dbo.PersonTable pt
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT dogName [dogName],dogAge  [dogAge], PersonID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY dogage DESC) DogRank
        FROM DogTable
    ) pet ON pet.PersonId = pt.Id
     AND pet.DogRank = 1
WHERE
    pt.firstName = 'john'
```

If a person has multiple 6 year old dogs, you could use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` to return both dogs.  If you just want one of them, stick with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` and don't use any of that fancy SQL (`PARTITIONS`, `RANK`, etc. etc.). Just use plain old SQL, like this ...

```
SELECT
    pt.firstName [FirstName],
    pt.lastName [LastName],
    joinQuery.dogName [dogName]
FROM dbo.PersonTable pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DogTable joinQuery ON joinQuery.PersonId = pt.id
WHERE joinQuery.dogAge = (SELECT MAX(dt.dogAge)
                          FROM DogTable dt WHERE dt.PersonId = pt.id)
AND pt.firstName = 'john'
```

Comment: I guess ROW_NUMBER() and RANK() might be 'fancy' to some, but they allow for greater efficiency than what you've got going on here.

Comment: @Goat_CO No hard feelings. I prefer (by far) standard SQL that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `APPLY`. `OUTER APPLY` corresponds to an outer join, and `CROSS APPLY` corresponds to an inner join. See

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

and

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

```
SELECT
    pt.firstName [FirstName],
    pt.lastName [LastName],
    joinQuery.dogName [dogName]
FROM dbo.PersonTable pt
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 1
            dt.dogName [dogName],
            dt.dogAge  [dogAge]
        FROM
            DogTable dt
        WHERE dt.PersonId = pt.Id
        ORDER BY dt.dogAge
    ) joinQuery
WHERE
    pt.firstName = 'john'
```